# Updating Record access Level

Tags: sharing, roles, owd

On Account object - OWD as Private
I have a requirement consist of Two roles as 
1. Process Owner - Creator of accounts
2. Manager Team - Verification team having access to those accounts

We have introduced **verified** checkbox field in **Account**
This field is read only to Process Owner

When process owner creates an Account, an email alert will shoot to Manager Team with subject as "Please verify account".
When **Manager Team** user verified the account details he will checked the "verified" field,
after saving we need to make the record read only to process owner means though he is a account owner he should not edit that record because its verified by manager team

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be through a validation rule, but this would be a little annoying since it wouldn't fire until the user tried to edit and save the record.
You could also add an approval process which can control record accessibility more info [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_creating_approval_processes.htm&language=en_US#Approver):

> Specify Approver Field and Record Editability
>
> When you define approval steps, you can assign approval requests to
>   different users. One option is to use a user field to automatically
>   route these requests. The user field can be any custom hierarchical
>   relationship field such as Account Manager or the Manager standard
>   user field. To see some examples of specifying a user field as an
>   approver field, see Examples of Approval Processes.
>
> When a record is in the approval process, it is always locked; only an
>   administrator can edit it. However, you can also allow the
>   currently-assigned approver to edit the record. You can still add
>   campaign members to campaigns locked for approval.
>
> From the Next Automated Approver Determined By picklist, select a user
>   field if you want Salesforce to automatically assign approval requests
>   to an approver based on the value in the user field. For example, you
>   may want approval requests automatically routed to a user's manager as
>   specified in the Manager standard user hierarchy field. Or, you may
>   want approval requests automatically routed to an associate specified
>   in a custom Account Manager user field.
>
> To specify a user to approve all approval requests, leave this field
>   blank. You can select a user, or users, as the approver when creating
>   an approval step.
>
> Warning
>
> If you leave the Next Automated Approver Determined By field blank,
>   you can't automatically assign approval requests to the manager in any
>   step you create for this approval process.
>
> Select Use Approver Field of Record Owner if you want the first
>   executed approval step to use a standard or custom user hierarchy
>   field on the record owner's user record—instead of the submitter's
>   user record—as the approver. All remaining steps use the specified
>   user hierarchy field in the user record of the preceding step’s
>   approver.
>
> For example, suppose you want the approval process to automatically
>   assign each step’s approver using the Manager standard user hierarchy
>   field. The first approval step that isn’t skipped uses the record
>   owner’s manager as the approver. All the other steps use the preceding
>   approver’s manager as the approver.
>
> Note
>
> Make sure the assigned approver has access to read the records for the
>   approval requests. For example, a user who does not have read access
>   to an Expenses custom object will not be able to view expense approval
>   requests.
>
> Select Administrators ONLY... if you want only users with the “Modify
>   All” object-level permission for the given object, or the “Modify All
>   Data” permission, to be able to edit records that are pending
>   approval. Select Administrators OR... if you want the assigned
>   approver to be able to edit the records too. The assigned approver
>   must also have edit access to the record through both their
>   permissions and the organization-wide sharing defaults for the given
>   object. When a record is submitted for approval, it is automatically
>   locked to prevent other users from editing it during the approval
>   process.
>
> Click Next. If you are editing an existing approval process and don't
>   want to make further changes, click Save to store your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the scenario and I've managed to fulfill your requirement by having two profiles, one for Process Owner and the other for Manager team. Then I went to field accessibility and set the checkbox as read-only for Process Owner and editable for Manager team.

I've create a record with the Process Owner and the user didn't had permission to edit that field. Logged in as a user with the profile Manager Team and edited the field which then showed as ticked but read-only when I logged in as Process Owner.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an approval process.

Approval processes are for exactly what you specify: a user, or group of users verifies that some part of a business process is allowed to continue.

You can also make it so that the "Verified" flag is set as a result of the approval process being completed.

The nice thing about this is that locking the record takes place regardless of ownership. Normally ownership will drive the ability to read/write to a record. So you won't have to fiddle with the ownership throughout the process. The process owner, can remain record owner through the lifespan of the record in question.

**Beware of forward looking statements below!!!**

The only downside to this solution is having to manually submit for approval. But even this will change in the near future with the Lightning Process Builder. The Lightning Process Builder features a "Submit For Approval" action so you could make it be that the approval only occurs when certain conditions exist. If you want to work with LPB, get in touch with Salesforce support. It is in beta, but must be enabled currently.